# How to create an infinite loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am dealing with jQuery animation with infinite loop and my code is below:

```js
var width = $(document).width() - $('#mydiv').width();
$(document).ready(function() {
  function animateMydiv() {
    $('#mydiv').animate({
        'left': width + 'px'
      }, 9000,

      function() {
        $('#test').css({
          opacity: 1.0,
          visibility: "visible"
        }, 9000).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, 9000);
      }).animate({
      'left': '0px'
    }, 9000);
  }

  animateMydiv();
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}
#test {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<p id="test">
  Hi welcome...!!
</p>
```

I used `animateMydiv()` to loop infinite but it not worked.

Comment: `but it not worked`, define not working, does it throw errors?

Comment: add in jsfiddle

Comment: It only animate once, I want it infinite

Comment: Infinite loop? `while (true) { }`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand a problem but try to use setInterval()?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for JS code here, you can achieve what you're doing using CSS alone using `@keyframes` and `animation`. Try this:

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  animation: slider 9s infinite; 
}
#test {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50;
  animation: blinker 9s infinite; 
}
@keyframes slider {
  0% { left: 0; }
  50% { left: 95%; }
  100% { left: 0; }
}
@keyframes blinker {
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  55% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<p id="test">
  Hi welcome...!!
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
function animateMydiv() {
    $('#mydiv').animate({'left': width + 'px'}, 9000, function(){
        $('#test').css({opacity:1.0, visibility:"visible"}, 9000).animate({opacity: 0}, 9000);
    }).animate({'left': '0px'}, 9000, animateMydiv); 
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8ujL2288/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var width = $(document).width() - $('#mydiv').width();
$(document).ready(function() {
  function animateMydiv() {
    $('#mydiv').animate({
        'left': width + 'px'
      }, 9000,

      function() {
        $('#test').css({
          opacity: 1.0,
          visibility: "visible"
        }, 9000).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, 9000);
      }).animate({
      'left': '0px'
    }, 9000);
window.setTimeout(animateMydiv, 100);
  }

  window.setTimeout(animateMydiv, 100);
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}
#test {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<p id="test">
  Hi welcome...!!
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function to the same function, more on callback functions can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp). Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/nopamz7e/).

```js
var width = $(document).width() - $('#mydiv').width();
$(document).ready(function() {
    function animateMydiv() {
        $('#mydiv').animate({
                'left': width + 'px'
            }, 9000,

            function() {
                $('#test').css({
                    opacity: 1.0,
                    visibility: "visible"
                }, 9000).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 9000);
            }).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 9000,animateMydiv);
    }
    animateMydiv();
});
```

```css
#mydiv
{
width:40px;
height:40px;
position:absolute;
left:0; 
background: black;
}

#test
{
 visibility: hidden;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">  
</div>
<p id="test">
Hi welcome...!!
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got answer for this by using

```
window.setInterval(animateMydiv, 9000);
```

in above jquery..!!

Comment: any idea how to calculate width in                                                            var width = $(document).width() - $('#mydiv').width();                                         Because I want this animation for mobile also..